# How to get currency symbol from currency code for all available locales in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have currency code (for example: "UAH"). In my code I get currency symbol equal currency code ("UAH"), but for "USD" and "EUR" - "$" and "€". Why?

```
let currencyCode = "UAH"

let localeComponents = [NSLocaleCurrencyCode: currencyCode]

let localeIdentifier = NSLocale.localeIdentifierFromComponents(localeComponents)

let locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: localeIdentifier)

let currencySymbol = locale.objectForKey(NSLocaleCurrencySymbol)
```

**I found solution:**

```
let locales: NSArray = NSLocale.availableLocaleIdentifiers()
for localeID in locales as! [NSString] {
    let locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: localeID as String)
    let code = locale.objectForKey(NSLocaleCurrencyCode) as? String
    if code == "UAH" {
        let symbol = locale.objectForKey(NSLocaleCurrencySymbol) as? String
    print(symbol!)
    break
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it "US$" for USD? And what it should be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because your `locale` wasn't set up correctly. The system knows nothing about your locale other than its currency code. There are two dozens or so locales with `USD` as the currency code; their currency symbols vary between `US$` and `$`. `UAH` has 2 available locales: `ru_UA` and `uk_UA`.

A safer way is to iterate over all locales that have the same currency code as you have specified, then use a rule to pick from the resulting list:

```
let currencyCode = "UAH"

let currencySymbols = NSLocale
                        .availableLocaleIdentifiers()
                        .map { NSLocale(localeIdentifier: $0) }
                        .filter {
                            if let localeCurrencyCode = $0.objectForKey(NSLocaleCurrencyCode) as? String {
                                return localeCurrencyCode == currencyCode 
                            } else {
                                return false
                            }
                        }
                        .map {
                           ($0.localeIdentifier, $0.objectForKey(NSLocaleCurrencySymbol)!)
                        }

print(currencySymbols) // Now you can choose from the list
```

Comment: Thank's for answer. But I found solution with less code.

Comment: @qwerty-reloader can you share that solution?

Comment: Yes. My solution in top.

Comment: **Swift3** let currencyCode = "UAH"

let curr = Locale.availableIdentifiers.map{ Locale(identifier: $0)}.filter {
        return currencyCode == $0.currencyCode
    }.map {  ($0.identifier, $0.currencySymbol) }.flatMap {$0}.first
print(curr)